# Google Sheets: Pivot table filtering and sorting multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, pivot-table

I'm facing a slight problem with expanding columns I'd like to use in my pivot table. I have a data sheet with many information, and I want to make a pivot out of it which filters information.

[Raw data][image: 1]

[Desired outcome][image: 2]

I'd like to filter only volumes with status "Planned", grouped by the client in a particular delivery place. I'm trying to use query formula, but it seems that's not the tool I shall be using to solve this problem. I've been thinking about making query table with index&match in other columns, but it seems to be like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({"Week "&WEEKNUM(A2:A)\ B2:E}; 
 "select Col2,Col3,sum(Col4) 
  where Col5 = 'Planned' 
  group by Col2,Col3 
  pivot Col1"))
```

[image]